# Wordpress: Display "Today" or "Tomorrow" on posts

Tags: php, wordpress, date, datetime

I am setting up a new wordpress website. I am using a template which includes the following code to display the post date:

```
<?php if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; } ?>

<?php
if( $post_Style == 'dt-sc-simple-style' || $post_Style == 'dt-sc-title-overlay-style' || $post_Style == 'dt-sc-simple-withbg-style' || $post_Style == 'dt-sc-overflow-style'  ):
    echo sprintf( esc_html__( '%s ago', 'saara' ), human_time_diff( get_the_date('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) );
elseif( $post_Style == 'dt-sc-overlap-style' ):
    echo esc_html__('on ', 'saara').get_the_date ( get_option('date_format') ).esc_html__(' at ', 'saara').get_the_time('', $post_ID);
elseif( $post_Style == 'dt-sc-classic-style' || $post_Style == 'dt-sc-classic-ii-style' ): ?>
    <i class="pe-icon pe-date"> </i>
    <?php echo get_the_date ( get_option('date_format') );
else: ?>
    <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"> </i>
    <?php echo get_the_date ( get_option('date_format') );
endif; ?>
```

My question is, how should I modify this code for example the last part:

```
<?php echo get_the_date ( get_option('date_format') );
```

in order to display "Today" or "Tomorrow" (when is the case) and if not, leave the dates as is.

I have found this resource:
https://studiosimpati.co/developer-center/show-words-today-tomorrow-advanced-custom-field-date/

And I tried to adapt it, however, my coding skills are not good and I didn't manage to make it work.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: Just compare `get_the_date` (expect format `YYYY-mm-dd`) with `date('Y-m-d')` and `date('Y-m-d', strtotime(+1 day))`. If get_the_date returns another date format, first format that into `YYYY-mm-dd` or `timestamp`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, however, I do believe that I can understand the logic but I cannot make the code work. Could you please be more specific? Thank you once again!

Comment: Not an answer, just comment. Everything was written, make a little research. Won't give you whole code, this is PHP basics.

Comment: Then I am sorry, but as I explained at my initial comment my coding skills are very very basic and I cannot make this work. Thanks once again for your comments.

Comment: so it's the highest time to improve your skills from 0/100 to 2/100 :-) What you need is on 2nd-3rd capture of each PHP book/tutorial. Really won't give you complete code to copy&paste.

Comment: Thanks, I will try again.